# failed_when is causing a debug task to fail despite the conditional resulting in False?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to check that two variables are defined and not empty. I have a task `debug` with that checks that and if either of the two variables are undefined or empty, it should fail the task. The problem is that, when both are defined, the script returns (correctly) that they are both defined, but the `failed_when` condition still fails the task.

Here are my tasks:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_variable:
      version: "2"
      previous_version: "1"

- name: Ensure versions are present
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: |
      {% set missing_versions = [] %}
      {% set version_names = ['version','previous_version'] %}
      {% for version_name in version_names %}
        {% if my_variable[version_name] is not defined or my_variable[version_name] == '' %}
          {% set missing_versions = missing_versions + version_name %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% if missing_versions | length > 0 %}
        The following value(s) are missing: {{ missing_versions | join(', ') }}
      {% else %}
        The {{ version_names | join(', ') }} values are present.
      {% endif %}
  failed_when: missing_versions | length > 0
```

**Expected result**:

When `my_variable.version` and `my_variable.previous_version` are both defined:

> The version, previous_version values are present.

Else:

> The following value(s) are missing:
>
> - version
> - previous_version

As you can see in the `set_fact` task, both of those values are defined, and when the `debug` task runs it outputs *"The version, previous_version values are present."*, yet the task still fails. If I change the conditional to `failed_when: no`, it succeeds. I even added text in the task to check the exact same conditional:

```yaml
- name: Ensure versions are present
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: |
      {% set missing_versions = [] %}
      {% set version_names = ['version','previous_version'] %}
      {% for version_name in version_names %}
        {% if my_variable[version_name] is not defined or my_variable[version_name] == '' %}
          {% set missing_versions = missing_versions + version_name %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% if missing_versions | length > 0 %}
        The following value(s) are missing: {{ missing_versions | join(', ') }}
      {% else %}
        The {{ version_names | join(', ') }} values are present.
      {% endif %}
      Missing versions length > 0: {{ missing_versions | length > 0 }}
  failed_when: missing_versions | length > 0
```

Result:

> The version, previous_version values are present. \nMissing versions length > 0: False

So I know the conditional is correct, yet `failed_when` is still failing the task even when the result is `False`.

What am I missing? Also, I welcome any suggestions on improving my code to check that those two attributes aren't undefined/empty.

Comment: The variable `missing_versions` is local to your debug, and so, not accessible outside when the failure condition is evaluated

Comment: So is there a way to accomplish this in one task? I'm trying to avoid separate tasks if I can do it all in one jinja script/ filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a playbook fail for some reason(s) then, don't use a `debug` task, rather use an [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) one:

```yaml
 - assert:
     that:
       - my_variable.version | default('') | length > 0
       - my_variable.previous_version | default('') | length > 0
```

Using a [`default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default), here, will ensure that the assertion will fail because of the condition defined and not with a failure of the assertion task itself.

The outcome of such a task would either be:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed
```

or

```yaml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: my_variable.version | default('') | length > 0
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Assertion failed
```

And you can further customise those as you're pleased with the [`success_msg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html#parameter-success_msg) and [`failed_msg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html#parameter-failed_msg) parameters.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need. I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're not using that var before your assert task? Please edit your question with the new code.